# How to do Multi file find and replace from unix prompt

Tags: unix, replace, find

I want to replace 'localhost' with an actual ip like '1.1.1.1' in every file in a directory including subfolders, plus I want it to log the filenames it changed.  I'm having a difficult time doing this, what command should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -r --files-with-matches localhost *|tee changed_files|xargs sed -i 's/localhost/1.1.1.1/g'
```

The files changed will be logged to `changed_files`.

Answer (score 1):

`find /path/to/all/files -type f -exec sed -i 's/localhost/IP/g' {}\;` should work.  Or you get an idea of how to make sed work on every file that find finds.

Comment: It needs a semicolon at the end, that's what causes the "missing argument" error.

Comment: @David: thank you for the comment.  I will proof read my answers.  Included the missing semi-colon.